# Values from csv files from GCP Storage changed values when replacing string with None in python

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-storage

I'm reading in csv files stored on GCP Storage and I want to replace string 'na' with None. The end table has some really messed up data points so I made some samples to illustrate the problem.

First, my code to read in csv files:

```
import pandas as pd
# Storage url is the url of the GCS that stores my files and 
# blob is the name of the desired file
data = pd.read_csv(storage_url+blob).replace('na', None)
print(data)
```

First csv sample:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
1,2,na,na,2
na,na,2,3,na
na,2,2,,5
5,56,4,5,2
na,4,6,7,na
```

Result:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
0    1    2   na   na    2
1    1    2    2    3    2
2    1    2    2  NaN    5
3    5   56    4    5    2
4    5    4    6    7    2
```

So you can see here that some values are replaced with `NaN` and some aren't.

For the second sample, not only some values are not replaced with `NaN`, their original 'na' string is replaced with a numeric value of a row before that.

```
construction_number,price_from_euro,price_to_euro,project_id,site_id
6,na,na,12023,17844
7,na,na,12023,17844
8,na,na,12023,17844
9,na,na,12023,17844
10,na,na,12023,17844
11,na,na,12023,17844
13,458000,458000,12023,17844
14,na,na,12023,17844
17,na,na,12023,17844
18,na,na,12023,17844
19,na,na,12023,17844
21,na,na,12023,17844
22,na,na,12023,17844
```

Result:

```
    construction_number price_from_euro price_to_euro  project_id  site_id
0                     6              na            na       12023    17844
1                     7              na            na       12023    17844
2                     8              na            na       12023    17844
3                     9              na            na       12023    17844
4                    10              na            na       12023    17844
5                    11              na            na       12023    17844
6                    13          458000        458000       12023    17844
7                    14          458000        458000       12023    17844
8                    17          458000        458000       12023    17844
9                    18          458000        458000       12023    17844
10                   19          458000        458000       12023    17844
11                   21          458000        458000       12023    17844
12                   22          458000        458000       12023    17844
```

So you can see that there's only 1 row with `price_from_euro=458000`, in the read pandas dataframe there are now 7. What is going on? I don't need a solution I just want to understand why this is the case. I haven't found any answers online.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `na_values='na'`:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO # for reproducibility

csv1 = """col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
1,2,na,na,2
na,na,2,3,na
na,2,2,,5
5,56,4,5,2
na,4,6,7,na"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv1), na_values='na')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0   1.0   2.0   NaN   NaN   2.0
1   NaN   NaN   2.0   3.0   NaN
2   NaN   2.0   2.0   NaN   5.0
3   5.0  56.0   4.0   5.0   2.0
4   NaN   4.0   6.0   7.0   NaN
```

When pandas is trying to parse your file, it tries to determine the type of the column, your columns have numbers AND strings so I think it is getting confused. Pandas works best when the columns are typed.

If we run:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv1), na_values='na')
print(df.dtypes)
```

We get:

```
col1    float64
col2    float64
col3    float64
col4    float64
col5    float64
```

And without `na_values='na'`:

```
col1    object
col2    object
col3    object
col4    object
col5    object
```